# Add Magnific Popup to items Dynamically

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I use Magnific Popup Plugin for popup. The divs get class="item" dynamically, so after that when I click on the div, the popup do not work.

```
$('.item').magnificPopup({ 
    type: 'image',
    gallery:{
        enabled:true
    },
    fixedContentPos: false  
});
```

Comment: Did you see the console? Does the control actually get class named item?  are you getting any error?

Comment: How/when does the `item` class get added?

Comment: I see the div gets the class="item".  The item class get added when I click on button.

Comment: you should bind the above action when you click the button then